# 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'cameraTexture' and '.CameraLayout'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is it an issue about `Xamarin.Forms` version? , I'm using  `Android.Hardware.Camera2;`

I'm initializing a view for Camera2, and based on the sample Project of [Camera2Forms](https://github.com/vtserej/Camera2Forms)

```
var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CameraLayout, this);
_cameraTexture = view.FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.cameraTexture);
```

but when i check my Resource designer `.CameraLayout` and `.camerTexture` is not present,
by the way both values are `int`, and when i try to brute force the value it returns `null`.

**Edit:**

   i missed the .axml file in the layout directory

Comment: Please try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in your project, rebuild your project. if this issue is disappear.

Comment: I download your project by the link. I can found the `CameraLayout`, I cannot run it at first. When I update all of the nuget packages to the latest. delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in your project. I can run it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions guys, but turns out i missed the .axml file in the layout directory

Comment: Ok, please post your solution to answer and mark it after three days, it will help others who have similar issue.